# fill 2d array python value from a list / 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop

How do I fill a 2d array value from an updated 1d list ?

for example I have a list that I get from this code :

```
a=[]
for k, v in data.items():
     b=v/sumcount
     a.append(b)
```

What I want to do is produce several 'a' list and put their value into 2d array with different column. OR put directly the b value into 2D array whic one colum represent loop for number of k.

*My difficulties here is, k is not integer. its dict keys (str). whose length=9

I have tried this but does not work :

```
row  = len(data.items())
matrix=np.zeros((9,2))
for i in range (1,3) :
    a=[]
    for k, v in data.items():
        b=v/sumcount
        matrix[x][i].fill(b), for x in range (1, 10)
```

a list is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and for example I do the outer loop, what I expect is
*for example 1 to 2 outer loop so I expect there will be 2 column and 9 row.

```
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5   14
6   15
7   16
8   17
9   18
```

I want to fill matrix value with b

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with real inputs and your *expected output*

Comment: "for example I have a list that I get from this code :" So, this doesn't really tell us enough information. Just *give us the list*. How it was created is not as relevant, what is relevant is *the actual value*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matrix = np.zeros((9, 2))

df = pd.DataFrame({'aaa': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

sumcount = [1, 2]
for i in range(len(sumcount)):
    matrix[:, i] = df['aaa']/sumcount[i]

print(matrix)
```

As far as I understand you: you need to get the result of the column from the dataframe and place it in a `numpy` array. No need to iterate over each row if your `sumcount` is the same number. This will work slowly. In general, loops are used as a last resort, if there is no other possibility.

[Slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) is used to set values in `numpy`.

```
bbb = np.array([df['aaa']/sumcount[i] for i in range(len(sumcount))]).transpose()
    
print(bbb)
```

Or do without a loop at all using `list comprehension`, wrap the result in `np.array` and apply [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.transpose.html).